# How can I add events to Google Calendar from inside an app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create a quick personal app for adding my work schedule to my Google Calendar, and I wanted to make the app for my phone, and not just my desktop. Basically, I have 8 different shifts I can work, and once I press a shift, the app moves to the next day asking me for the shift for that day. Allows me to add my schedule to my Google Calendar in a minute.

But can I add events to my Google Calendar from my phone? I have not seen a Google Calendar API as of yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be an OS level API for Google (this is a Microsoft OS!) but you should be able to do this yourself.

The Google Calendar API is - http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/

There is an official .net client - http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/client-cs.html - don't know if it works on WP7 or not - it might need some modification - at the very least it might need to be compiled into a Silverlight or WP7 specific library

There are some articles around on how to add events to Google - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/GoogleCalendarAndDotNet.aspx